# Pip install google-cloud-logging failed in docker

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I try to search the answer in stackoverflow and try to find something in the github [issues](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues) but nothing I found.
Can anyone give me some tip to solve the problem?

I get the following error when trying to install Google Cloud Logging by pip with docker:

```
test_web            |     import google.cloud.logging
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
test_web            |     from google.cloud.logging_v2 import __version__
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
test_web            |     from google.cloud.logging_v2.client import Client
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/client.py", line 25, in <module>
test_web            |     from google.cloud.logging_v2._helpers import _add_defaults_to_filter
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_helpers.py", line 25, in <module>
test_web            |     from google.cloud.logging_v2.entries import LogEntry
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/entries.py", line 33, in <module>
test_web            |     from google.iam.v1.logging import audit_data_pb2  # noqa: F401
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/iam/v1/logging/audit_data_pb2.py", line 32, in <module>
test_web            |     from google.iam.v1 import policy_pb2 as google_dot_iam_dot_v1_dot_policy__pb2
test_web            |   File "/root/site/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/iam/v1/policy_pb2.py", line 39, in <module>
test_web            |     _POLICY = DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name["Policy"]
test_web            | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'
```

I have it running in a virtual environment with this in requirements.txt:
`google-cloud-logging==3.0.0`

Comment: Also having this issue, bump this

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your protobuf to 3.20.1. Unsure why its happening. Here's the git issue: https://github.com/googleapis/python-iam/issues/185

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while using `google-cloud-secret-manager` and `poetry`.
Removing unused `gcloud` dependency as well as `google-cloud-secret-manager` and reinstalling `google-cloud-secret-manager` solved it.

```
poetry remove gcloud
poetry remove google-cloud-secret-manager
poetry add google-cloud-secret-manager
```